# CKEditor: insert HTML from clip-board at current insertion point in WYSIWYG mode?

Tags: ckeditor

It seems that to insert HTML into the source code in CKEditor one must view source, then scan down through the code to find the appropriate insertion point.

I have a situation where the user will have HTML in their clipboard, but will not be HTML proficient, and will have a tough time understanding where in the source they need to insert the clip of HTML

SO: Is there a way to get CKEditor to paste, into the source code, whatever is in the user's clipboard at the current insertion point while in WYSIWYG mode?

Would this require developing a plugin? If so, could anyone someone provide a high-level overview of how that would be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Embed Media plugin which is available.

Just add that plugin. Using that the user can paste the html code in a dialog box and that will be pasted in the editor wherever the cursor was.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug. Here's the URL for the iFrame that it generates: http://localhost:10113/Scripts/ckeditor/plugins/MediaEmbed//dialogs/mediaembed.html  ... it's choking on the double-slash ("bad request"). When I pasted that URL into my address bar with just one slash, I get the correct result.

Comment: RU involved with the project? if so, line 30 of MediEmbed/plugin.js needs to be edited: remove the slash just inside the opening single-quote:  +me.path+'/dialogs/mediaem ....  --> +me.path+'dialogs/mediaem... . After that, this works like a charm.

Comment: um, in the version of media embed plugin that i am using, me.path+'/dialogs/mediaem .... works fine...
check out your me.path, its not coming out right somehow, there shouldn't be a '/' after /plugin/MediaEmbed